# Http Starts failing after a while using windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, internet, wget

I have problem with my connection on windows 8.1, it looks fine when restart my system, for this wget call.

```
wget http://www.google.com/
```

as following result.

```
--2014-11-26 17:59:37--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.68.99, 74.125.68.105, 74.125.68.147, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.68.99|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=scd1VOzFJoTFoAOEvoCoBA [following]
--2014-11-26 17:59:37--  http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=scd1VOzFJoTFoAOEvoCoBA
Resolving www.google.co.in... 74.125.130.94
Connecting to www.google.co.in|74.125.130.94|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html@gfe_rd=cr&ei=scd1VOzFJoTFoAOEvoCoBA'

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                           ] 19,223      --.-K/s   in 0.05s

2014-11-26 17:59:37 (361 KB/s) - `index.html@gfe_rd=cr&ei=scd1VOzFJoTFoAOEvoCoBA' saved [19223]
```

But when I run this command again after say 1-5 hours (yes, since the time is very random), it goes off like this for the same command

```
--2014-11-26 17:53:21--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.68.103, 74.125.68.106, 74.125.68.147, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.68.103|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

which never returns anything ever after long time and then times out.

This also affects my local network, e.g. my localhost urls wold also stop working, if I use nodejs to start web server. it fails with error, not allowing me to listen to any port as http. But as soon as I restart my machine everything is fine for next few hours again.

This also applies to all browsers, I tried everything from Firefox, chrome, IE and even Opera.

Comment: I've had this happen since a week or 2 on one of my Windows 8.1 machines as well. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I'm going to try to see if this helps fixing my issue: http://adamralph.com/2014/01/24/continuously-losing-internet-connectivity-in-windows-8-1/